# Flutter AnimationController listener not firing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am attempting to use an AnimationController in my Bloc to send a series of images every couple of seconds to the Stateful Widget. The following code snippets show the setup. Although the animation ticker fires(which I can see via the ticker print statements), the listener never executes.

Any ideas?

```
 class RaspDataBloc extends Bloc<RaspDataEvent, RaspDataState>
    implements TickerProvider {
   ...
    void startImageAnimation() {
    _forecastImageAnimationController = AnimationController(
        value: 0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 15000),
        lowerBound: 0,
        upperBound: _forecastTimes.length.toDouble(),
        vsync: this)
      ..repeat()
      ..addListener(() {
        _postForecastImageSet(_forecastImageAnimationController.value);//  <<< doesn't execute
      });
    _forecastImageAnimationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Ticker createTicker(onTick) {     //  <<<< This executes
    print('Creating Ticker');
    return Ticker(tickerDuration);
  }

  tickerDuration(Duration elapsed) {
    print('Ticker duration:  $elapsed.inMilliseconds'); //<<<< This fires regularly as expected
  }

  Stream<RaspDataState> _postForecastImageSet(double value) async* {
    print("Animation value: $_forecastImageAnimationController.value");
    var imageIndex = value.toInt();
    if (imageIndex < _imageSets.length) {
      print("Posting imageSet[$imageIndex]");
      yield new RaspForecastImageDisplay(_imageSets[imageIndex]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason why you are using a `TickerProvider`? Typically with an `AnimationController` you use a `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`. If you do that, and add the listener after creating the animation controller in your `initState`, then your listener will work. Like this:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  initState(){
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2)
    );
    _animationController.addListener((){
      print('Animation Controller Listener');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to put the animation in the Bloc and not in the widget. The SingleTickerProviderStateMixin won't work with the Bloc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why do you want the animation on the bloc? Are you mixing business logic with view logic?

Comment: The images I am sending to the widget are for a series of google map overlays plus  'scale' images, plus some text. That is just the start of what I eventually need to display on the google map. I am basically rewriting an existing Java/Android app where the equivalent logic was in the ViewModel.

Comment: But really, my question remains. Why does the listener not fire?

Comment: I tried it myself and it wasn't firing for me either. Seems to either be an issue with a simple TickerProvider, or working as intended for a reason we don't know. You might want to open an issue with the Flutter team on GitHub. The apps in which I control animations from my single state management model still get their controllers instantiated on the views and then passed on to the single state to be manipulated. And the SingleTickerProviderStateMixin is in the Views as well.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation submitted issue -  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47824

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same problem just now, but the ticker works fine. You just have to start it.

> Ticker class
>
> Calls its callback once per animation frame.
>
> When created, a ticker is initially disabled. Call start to enable the ticker.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/Ticker-class.html

So basically:

```dart
TickerProvider provider; // get a TickerProvider from somewhere.
Ticker ticker = provider.createTicker((elapsed) => print('tick ($elapsed)'));
ticker.start();
```

which will result in something like:

```
I/flutter (28439): tick (0:00:00.000000)
I/flutter (28439): tick (0:00:00.050374)
I/flutter (28439): tick (0:00:00.067166)
I/flutter (28439): tick (0:00:00.218288)
I/flutter (28439): tick (0:00:00.235081)
```

Basically the time elapsed from the moment it started